# creating a table - is there a way to shorten this code?

Tags: python

I'm just starting out in Python, trying to invent exercises for myself.
I tried to create a table with numbers inside it, in such a way that the table would look clean and 'aesthetic'.

The code I wrote produces a table that looks like this:
[table in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gATH0.jpg)

I wrote the following code, but I'm sure there's a way to shorten it.

```
def draw_table(row, column):
    cel_number = range(1, (row * column) + 1 )
    column_counter = 1
    for n in cel_number:
        if column_counter < column:
            if n < 10:
                print(f"[{n}.   ]", end="")
            elif n >= 10 and n < 100:
                print(f"[{n}.  ]", end="")
            elif  n >= 100:
                print(f"[{n}. ]", end="")
            column_counter += 1
        else:
            if n < 10:
                print(f"[{n}.   ]")
            elif n >= 10 and n < 100:
                print(f"[{n}.  ]")
            elif  n >= 100:
                print(f"[{n}. ]")
            column_counter = 1
draw_table(6, 3)
```

Comment: i think you should post this on  codereview not on stackoverflow
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
def draw_table(row, column):
    line = ""
    for i in range(row * column):
        line += ("[{: <05}]".format(str(i+1) + '.'))
        if (i+1) % column == 0:
            print(line)
            line = ""

draw_table(6, 3)
```

Output :

```
[1.   ][2.   ][3.   ]
[4.   ][5.   ][6.   ]
[7.   ][8.   ][9.   ]
[10.  ][11.  ][12.  ]
[13.  ][14.  ][15.  ]
[16.  ][17.  ][18.  ]
```

or if you want it to be like in the image you provide, change one line to :

```
line += ("[{: >05}]".format('.' + str(i+1)))
```

and it will output :

```
[   .1][   .2][   .3]
[   .4][   .5][   .6]
[   .7][   .8][   .9]
[  .10][  .11][  .12]
[  .13][  .14][  .15]
[  .16][  .17][  .18]
```